# How can I solve this problem The GHC located at ___ failed to compile a sanity check. (windows)?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to use haskell on Windows with visual studio code, but when I use "stack setup", I got this error

> The GHC located at
>   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.6.5\bin\ghc-8.6.5.EXE
>   failed to compile a sanity check.

Comment: If you try to compile something manually with that GHC, what happens?

Comment: @JosephSible it works, but I need the stack to use Data.hashmap.lazy because I am not able to install it differently.

Comment: @JosephSible I got this error "Could find module Data.hashmap.lazy". If you know how to solve it using WinGHCI or Visual Studio Code will be great.